# Image change opacity on hover without jQuery

Tags: css, html, hover, opacity

I am trying to make a list of social buttons. When one button is hovered it lights up, and the other buttons should darken.

I got it to work partially. When the first button is hovered all works fine, but it is malfunctioning when the other buttons are hovered. I think this happens because all the latter list items are siblings of the first and the `:hover` event can't cause previous elements to change style.
Does anyone have any thoughts on how to get this to work?

Here's the code ([jsFiddle live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VnMFP/)):

```html
<div id="bg">

<ul id="social_buttons">
    <li id="item_1"><img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/104rasi.png"></li>
    <li id="item_2"><img src="http://i43.tinypic.com/k4tide.png"></li>
    <li id="item_3"><img src="http://i44.tinypic.com/2ry0gt3.png"></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

```css
#bg {
    height: 100px;
    width: 215px;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
}

#social_buttons img {
     width: 24px; 
     height: 24px;

    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}



#social_buttons {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 70px;

    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


#social_buttons li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;

    -webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}


/*  puur css3 multiple hover animaties */
#item_1 {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#item_1:hover ~ #item_2, :hover ~ #item_3 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#item_1:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}


#item_2 {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#item_2:hover ~ #item_1, :hover ~ #item_3 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#item_2:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

#item_3 {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#item_3:hover ~ #item_1, :hover ~ #item_2 {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#item_3:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Comment: @CodyGuldner the tinyurl-link is a jsfiddle ;-)

Comment: @bwoebi Code is nice to see in a question

Comment: You'd be surprised just how often jsfiddle is either down or exceptionally slow.

Comment: @CodyGuldner The jsfiddle can be reached with the tinyurl ;) stackoverflow would't let me post a jsfiddle link without code but i was it to much of a hurry to find out how to include code correctly

Comment: @WillemLeuverink I've put the code in for you. Click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17435158/edit) to see how I did it. In short, indent all code by four spaces. And with some languages on this site, including HTML and CSS, you also have to include a comment like `<!-- language: lang-css -->` so the language is highlighted correctly.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Thanks for putting the code in!

Comment: Three answers, all three work! thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy with the right selectors

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/screenmutt/VnMFP/5/)

```
ul li {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

ul:hover li {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

ul li:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/VnMFP/2/)?

```
#social_buttons:hover li {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#social_buttons li:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

General sibling selector (~) can't select preceding element, it works only in one direction.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/VnMFP/4/

```
#social_buttons li {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

#social_buttons:hover li {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#social_buttons li:hover {
    opacity: 0.9
}
```

Don't select the li:hover, select `ul#social_buttons:hover li`. Then it works.